# Create a session in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I can't for the life of me figure out how to create / use sessions in my project
My target framework is `4.5.2`

I've downloaded the NuGet package `Microsoft.AspNet.Session`
But all I can find online about sessions seems to be related do ASP.NET 5

How do you go about using sessions?

Thank you

Comment: Sessions have not significantly changed from 4.5 -> 5 so just use the example code here -> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate(v=vs.110).aspx and be done with it.

Comment: Wow, I've been looking at stuff that made it seem more difficult than it was, thank you!

Comment: Normally, you should not need Session State directly in ASP.Net MVC, although we use Session State and View State extensively in ASP.Net Web Form. What kind of information are you trying to persist?

Answer (score 1):

Assign it like this

```
Session["User"] = "Current";
```

Access it like this

```
if(Session["User"]!=null)
{
    string userName = Session["User"].ToString();
}
```